# Undefined control sequence makecvtitle in moderncv package

Tags: moderncv

I am using **moderncv** package in a tex document. I am compiling with pdflatex, and full [texlive](http://ctan.imsc.res.in/systems/texlive/Images/texlive2014-20140525.iso) package downloaded from CTAN. The error I'm getting is:

> line 7: Undefined control sequence \makecvtitle

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\name{Holmes}{Sherlock}
\insti{Institute Name}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are **2** `\documentclass` statements ;-) Remove one of them and it should work... Welcome to TeX.SX! ;-)

Comment: You are right. I have updated the CLS file. But, now facing a new problem. The resume template is using \insti command which is not supported by this newer version of the CLS file. Any workaround?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have added the MWE reproducing this issue. It compiles with 2013-02-09 v1.3.0 of moderncv package. For your convenience, I am uploading that specific version of [moderncv](http://www.mediafire.com/download/uq2kfisksa0pq43/2013-02-09__v1.3.0.zip).

Comment: Yeah, I did. The latest one does not recognize \insti command.

Answer (score 1):

A command `\insti` should not be accessed. You are not an institute but a person that hopefully is able to change it if desired.

I hope the following MWE (illustrating an institution of education and an institute where you have worked at or are currently working at) helps to explain why:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\name{Holmes}{Sherlock}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{Grade}{Majors}

\section{Work}
\cvitem{year--year}{Dishwasher at Institute Name}
\end{document}
```